# Attach an event handler to iframe inside iframe recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to attach an event handler to each iframes inside my page and also to iframes inside each iframes founded.

My event handler should be attached recursively to every page's iframe.
How can I find all iframe recursively with jQuery attaching an defined event handler to each of them? All iframes come from the same domain/subdomain.

I've tried this script but it doesn't work properly.

```js
$(function() {
    document.domain = 'mydomain.eu';
    $.each($('iframe'), searchForIframe);
});

var searchForIframe = function(index, element){
    $(element).contents().get(0).domain = 'mydomain.eu';
    console.log($(element).contents().get(0).domain);
    var title = $(element).attr("src");
    console.log('title: '+title+' index: '+index);
    var iframes = $(element).contents().find('iframe');
    console.log(iframes);
    $.each(iframes, searchForIframe);
};
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `window.frames` lists all frames (not that anyone uses them) and iframes of the current document - for each iframe found, look through it's `frames` - etc

Comment: `I need to attach an event handler to each iframes` Why woud you need this behaviour?

Comment: since this only works on same domain iframes, I'd write code in each frame to execute a predefined function in `window.top` which does whatever you want

Comment: @JaromandaXI need to do it, because I've to track every click in the page (including clicks into iframes).
I've to do this with jquery.

Comment: @A.Wolff I need to do it, because I've to track every click in the page (including clicks into iframes).
I've to do this with jquery.